# how do i determine oracle database name of data source

Tags: database, oracle

I've been searching around and haven't found anything on my scenario that I understand:

I have a list of all of the Oracle databases and corresponding servers that my company owns (about `80 servers 150 databases`). I am trying to figure out which one a specific file is being downloaded from (from a webpage).

I am mechanical engineer, not in software so if you could eli5 that would be very helpful.

> Specifically I need the SID name, but figuring out the server name
>   would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is kind of tricky here. if your downloading the file from web application(I assuming it is a Java webapp), oracle database could act as either the data store or a report server that can generate the oracle reports directly

In the first case, you need to find out if what kind of file you are downloading?
is it a PDF? is it a excel file? or just text file or anything? the best idea is to check out the file link and then decide what software generating this file. it could be any software in back end to generate the file like, POI(for generating excel file), or even a direct file link, but not oracle at all.

Also, In this case, the file is usually generated at backend by server-let. You need ask the developer which report or file generating engine they are employing. and if oracle database is also being used, it is usually providing the data fro that report or file engine.

In the second case, you can just check out the the URL and give it to the webmaster asking them which oracle server it is using. it is usually configured in the web server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe that the database acts just as the data store.  It might be helpful for you to know that prior to the file download, the data has already been pulled from the server.  Basically I go to the webapp, fill out a bunch of fields specifying the data I want, then click a "Generate Report" button.  The information is collected (from what I can tell) from the database and shown on screen in a table. At this point I have the option to download in my chosen format.  (Excel, HTML, TIFF, PDF, CSV, XML)  Maybe this will help